# Struct with array issue in C

Tags: c, struct, embedded

Edited:
Working with a Microchip bootloader that includes emulated EEPROM capability.
I declare a struct as per their example, except that I include an array rather than `int somevar`. `&eeVars` is passed to the code shown from ezbl.h
Problem is that sizeof always yields `2`, so that only the first member of my array is written by `EZBL_ModifyROM`. If I add a `*` to the last line of `EZBL_WriteROMObj`, sizeof gives the correct result and everything is written.

The ezbl.h if statement to test for an array always returns false. I have tested with an array without a struct, an array within a struct(as below), just `int somevar` in a struct, and 2 int variables in a struct.

As is, the only case that works with the always false if statement is a single `int somevar`. By adding the `*` dereference to the else case, everything works. Is there a reason to test for an array? Is there a need for the 2 cases?

For example, this code should print "65535" on first powerup, "10" the next powerup, and increment by 1 each subsequent powerup if all values in the array have been written.

```
EZBL_AllocFlashHole(emuEEData, 3072, 0x800, -1);
struct
{
 int MY_LUT[101];
} eeVars;

int main(void) {

EZBL_ReadROMObj(&eeVars, EZBL_FlashHoleAddr(emuEEData)); //read the stored data

printf("%d", MY_LUT[10]);

if(eeVars.MY_LUT[10] == 0xFFFF) //check if any values present
{
int i = 0;
for (i=0;i<101;i++)
{MY_LUT[i] = 10;}
}
else
{
MY_LUT[10] = MY_LUT[10] + 1;
}

EZBL_WriteROMObj(EZBL_FlashHoleAddr(emuEEData),&eeVars); //write the data
}
```

The ezbl.h code in question

```
#define EZBL_WriteROMObj(destPgmAddr, srcRAMObjPtr)                                                  
{                                                                                               
    EZBL_NVMKey = 0x03DF;                                                                       
    if(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof (srcRAMObjPtr), void*)) //always returns false
/* regular pointer case */   \
    EZBL_ModifyROM((destPgmAddr), (srcRAMObjPtr), sizeof(*srcRAMObjPtr));                   
    else /* array case  */ 
EZBL_ModifyROM((destPgmAddr), (srcRAMObjPtr), sizeof(srcRAMObjPtr));   

}

void EZBL_ModifyROM(unsigned long destPgmAddr, void *srcData, unsigned   int byteLen);
```

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. Including a *valid* macro definition, and how it is used.

Comment: Your code doesn't use `eeVars` anywhere... And that macro will be defined as empty because its definition doesn't include the following lines.

Comment: It is Microchip's code. srcRAMobjPtr is &eeVars and comes from a line of their code inserted into Main which calls EZBL_WriteROMObj shown above. Everything does work if I dereference the pointer in sizeof(srcRAMObjPtr). But then why the 2 cases?

Comment: Because you take the size of a _pointer_ which is 2 bytes on PIC or AVR.

Answer (score -1):

`sizeof` returns the size of an array in bytes if an array is passed in, like:

```
int MY_LUT[101];
printf("%d", sizeof(MY_LUT)); //prints 101 * sizeof(int)
```

If you are passing in a pointer to a struct containing an array, then to get the full size of the struct you would dereference it:

```
#define EZBL_WriteROMObj(destPgmAddr, srcRAMObjPtr)\
{\
  printf("%d", sizeof(*srcRAMObjPtr));\
}  
...
struct
{
 int MY_LUT[101];
} eeVars;
...
EZBL_WriteROMObj(addr, &eeVars);
```

If you knew your struct is only going to contain the array and nothing else, you could get at the size of the array with `sizeof(srcRAMObjPtr->MY_LUT)` but that would make the code less flexible, why do that when you can simply dereference the pointer?

---

The `EZBL_WriteROMObj` macro seems to attempt to determine whether the passed parameter is an array, but it's wrong, because `void*` is not the same type as `struct eevars*` or any other pointer. A better way to check whether the parameter is an array, using GNU extensions, would be:

```
#define EZBL_WriteROMObj(destPgmAddr, srcRAMObjPtr)\
{\                                            
    if(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(srcRAMObjPtr), typeof(&(srcRAMObjPtr)[0])))\
    {\
        /* regular pointer case */ \
        printf("%d\n", sizeof(*srcRAMObjPtr));\
        EZBL_ModifyROM((destPgmAddr), (srcRAMObjPtr), sizeof(*srcRAMObjPtr));\
    }\
    else /* array case  */ \
    {\
        printf("%d\n", sizeof(srcRAMObjPtr));\
        EZBL_ModifyROM((destPgmAddr), (srcRAMObjPtr), sizeof(srcRAMObjPtr));\
    }\
}
```

This way, you can pass either a pointer to the structure, or the array:

```
struct
{
    int MY_LUT[101];
} eeVars;
...
EZBL_WriteROMObj(addr, &eeVars);
/* or: */
EZBL_WriteROMObj(addr, eeVars.MY_LUT);
```

Comment: Yes, I believe the intent is that you can just drop into the struct anything you want to save to non-volatile memory. Provided you have allocated enough memory. I have dereferenced the pointer as per my initial post and then the code works fine. But then why did MC need both cases??

Comment: Ah just saw that, well yes it looks like it's trying to handle both cases and let you pass in either a struct pointer or an array, but I don't think that's the right way to do that. You might want to test that, but I don't think you can compare a struct pointer to a void pointer like that. There are better ways of checking if something's an array.

Comment: I have tested with 1. an array, 2. struct with array member as in my first post 3. struct with an int variable member, 4. struct with 2 int variables. In all cases the if statement returns "false".

Comment: Your macro does not check whether the parameter is an array properly. See the edit.